# Is it possible to save a VBO in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, opengl

Hey guys I am messing around with openGL and I am currently drawing a simple cube and I am wondering if I store the VBO/IBO/CBO in my cube class?

Like:

```
class Cube {
     private:
       GLuint vBO;
       GLuint cBO;
       GLuint iBO;
```

And then I would call:

```
 void Cube::setupDataBuffer() {
    glGenBuffers(1, &vBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexBufferData), vertexBufferData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &iBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indexBufferData), indexBufferData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenBuffers(1, &cBO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(colorBufferData), colorBufferData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

But if I then want to draw the cube in my main.cpp nothing appears, however if I put the VBO/CBO/IBO in my main and execute the other code there as well the cube appears.

So my question would be: How can I generate and bind bufferobjects in my class? I am working with opengl 3.3 by the way

Comment: "*How can I generate and bind bufferobjects in my class?*" Code doesn't change just because it's "in my class." So if you know how to use buffer objects at all, then you should be able to use them from inside of a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
void Cube::draw() {
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vBO);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
    glVertexAttribPointer(...);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cBO);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(...);
    glVertexAttribPointer(...);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iBO);
    glDrawElements(...);
}
```

This does all the context setup you need on an object-by-object basis.